# Is there a way to see any tar progress per file?

Tags: unix, tar, progress

I have a couple of big files that I would like to compress. I can do this with for example

```
tar cvfj big-files.tar.bz2 folder-with-big-files
```

The problem is that I can't see any progress, so I don't have a clue how long it will take or anything like that. Using `v` I can at least see when each file is completed, but when the files are few and large this isn't the most helpful.

Is there a way I can get tar to show more detailed progress? Like a percentage done or a progress bar or estimated time left or something. Either for each single file or all of them or both.

Answer (score 219, accepted):

I prefer oneliners like this:

```
tar cf - /folder-with-big-files -P | pv -s $(du -sb /folder-with-big-files | awk '{print $1}') | gzip > big-files.tar.gz
```

It will have output like this:

```
4.69GB 0:04:50 [16.3MB/s] [==========================>        ] 78% ETA 0:01:21
```

**For OSX** (from Kenji's answer)

```
tar cf - /folder-with-big-files -P | pv -s $(($(du -sk /folder-with-big-files | awk '{print $1}') * 1024)) | gzip > big-files.tar.gz
```

**Explanation**:

- `tar` tarball tool
- `cf` create file
- `-` use stdout instead of a file (to be able to pipe the output to the next command)
- `/folder-with-big-files` The input folder to zip
- `-P` use absolute paths (not necessary, see comments)

pipe to

- `pv` progress monitor tool
- `-s` use the following size as the total data size to transfer (for % calculation)

  - `$(...)` evaluate the expression
  - `du -sb /folder-with-big-files` disk usage summarize in one line with bytes. Returns eg `8367213097      folder-with-big-files`
  - pipe (|) to `awk '{print $1}'` which returns only the first part of the `du` output (the bytes, removing the foldername)

pipe to

- `gzip` gzip compression tool
- `big-files.tar.gz` output file name

Comment: On OSX, du does not take -b argument, needed to fallback to : $((du -sk /folder-with | awk '{print $1}') * 1024))

Comment: Nice, a one liner. Can you explain it? Or does it just magically work somehow?

Comment: Can you write command to extract tar file like above?

Comment: Ok, I have it
`pv $FILE.tgz | tar xzf - -C $DEST_DIR`

Comment: For OS X, I needed to use the square bracket form for arithmetic expansion, which made: `tar cf - /folder-with-big-files -P | pv -s $[$(du -sk /folder-with-big-files | awk '{print $1}') * 1024] | gzip > big-files.tar.gz` Without this change, I was getting `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token ')'`

Comment: Any idea how to make this work with `pixz`? For me, it works with `gzip`, `pigz` and `xz`, but not with `pixz`, `pxz` or when specifying multiple cores to   xz (`xz -T<num>`)

Comment: I've wrapped this oneliner in a bash function here: https://github.com/equant/my_bash_tools/blob/master/tarp.bash

Comment: thanks! I used it for backing up my home dir https://gist.github.com/timabell/68d112d66623d9a4a3643c86a93debee

Comment: Hello, how to do it for combining multiple directory/files into a one zip file?

Comment: Note that the progress doesn't show until the du command finishes which could take a while depending on the size, complexity, and fragmentation of the directory.

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party, but I was wondering why this answer suggests the use of the -P option on tar.  That seems like bad advice, given that the OP didn't mention a need for absolute paths in the tarball (and having them can cause real headaches when it comes time to extract the archive).

Comment: @KrzysztofSzewczyk this does not work with a tar.xz archive. i tried variants of `pv archive.tar.xz | tar xf - -C ~/location`, `pv archive.tar.xz | tar xf -J -C ~/location`, `pv archive.tar.xz | tar xf --C ~/location`, `pv archive.tar.xz | tar xf -JC ~/location`, ... but none seem to work. without pv it's : `tar xf archive.tar.xz -C ~/location`

Comment: okay I figured it out thanks to this :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/19372542/4770754 , it's :`pv archive.tar.xz | tar xp -J -C ~/location`

Comment: For those who only want to `tar` without compression on macOS: `tar -c folder-with-big-files | pv -s $[$(du -sk folder-with-big-files | awk '{print $1}') * 1024] > folder-with-big-files.tar`.

Comment: what in the world is 'pv'? doesnt seem to exist on Mac OS X

Comment: Might I suggest using `cut` instead of `awk` for this?  Like `cut -f1` instead of `awk '{print $1}'`?

Comment: The reason why I suggest is that it's a little less fault-prone, and is a much lighter command.

Comment: @qodeninja you can install [pv](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) on Mac OS X whit [home-brew](https://brew.sh) `brew install pv`, hope this will help you.

Comment: For multiple folders I used: `tar cf - folder1 folder2 folder3 -P | pv -s $(du -csb folder1 folder2 folder3 | grep total | awk '{print $1}') | gzip > archive.tar.gz`

Comment: Also if you install `zstd` (`brew install zstd`), replacing `gzip` with `zstd` on my system was 10x faster (~20 MB/s vs 300 MB/s).

Answer (score 83):

Use [`pv`](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml). To report the progress correctly, `pv` needs to know how many bytes you are throwing at it. So, the first step is to calculate the size (in kbyte). You can also completely drop the progress bar and just let `pv` tell you how many bytes it has seen; it would report a 'done that much and that fast'.

```
% SIZE=`du -sk folder-with-big-files | cut -f 1`
```

And then:

```
% tar cvf - folder-with-big-files | pv -p -s ${SIZE}k | \ 
     bzip2 -c > big-files.tar.bz2
```

Comment: Cool. `pv` doesn't seem to come with Mac OS X, but will try this out once I have a computer with MacPorts on it. Could you explain what you are doing there though? Not quite sure what the first line does exactly.

Comment: first line: fetch info about how many bytes will be handled. second line: use the size from the first line to allow pv to render 'progress'. since you are piping data, pv does not know how many more bytes will come.

Comment: One addition: `SIZE=$(($SIZE * 1000 / 1024))` - I don't know whether or not this is a quirk on my particular platform, so I'm not adding it to the answer:  `du` returns size where 1 kb = 1024 bytes, while `pv` seems to be expecting 1 kb = 1000 bytes.  (I'm on Ubuntu 10.04)

Comment: @lzkata you could always ask `du` to use your preferred blocksize, e.g. `du -s --block-size=1000`, or just work with plain bytes, e.g. drop the `k`'s from the `du` and `pv` calls. Nevertheless, I would expect both to use `1024` unless told otherwise, e.g. the `--si` switch on `du`, for example.

Comment: or just drop the k-stuff and just use plain bytes (`du -sb` and `pv -s` without any modifier). that should end all the confusion.

Comment: Any idea how to make this work with `pixz`? For me, it works with `gzip`, `pigz` and `xz`, but not with `pixz`, `pxz` or when specifying multiple cores to   xz (`xz -T<num>`)

Answer (score 35):

better progress bar..

```
apt-get install pv dialog

(pv -n file.tgz | tar xzf - -C target_directory ) \
2>&1 | dialog --gauge "Extracting file..." 6 50
```

[image]

Comment: This is works for extraction, but you still need to do one of the more complicated commands for creation (which was the original question). It could still be combined with those; it's just more complicated.

Answer (score 31):

Check out the `--checkpoint` and `--checkpoint-action` options in the tar info page (as for my distribution, the description for these options is not contained in the man page → RTFI).

See https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/checkpoints.html

With these (and maybe the functionality to write your own checkpoint command), you can calculate a percentage…

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Others just explain extra tools (not installed by default, besides) to achieve something similar.

Comment: @Sardathrion Maybe because it's GNU-`tar` specific.

Answer (score 28):

Inspired by [helper’s answer](https://superuser.com/a/319207/726186)

Another way is use the native `tar` options

```
FROMSIZE=`du -sk --apparent-size ${FROMPATH} | cut -f 1`;
CHECKPOINT=`echo ${FROMSIZE}/50 | bc`;
echo "Estimated: [==================================================]";
echo -n "Progess:   [";
tar -c --record-size=1K --checkpoint="${CHECKPOINT}" --checkpoint-action="ttyout=>" -f - "${FROMPATH}" | bzip2 > "${TOFILE}";
echo "]"
```

the result is like

```
Estimated: [==================================================]
Progess:   [>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

a complete example [here](http://www.campisano.org/wiki/en/Script_bkp.sh)

Comment: This is an amazing approach - thanks for sharing it! The progress bar might not completely match the estimate bar more often than not but it's usually only a "off-by-one" error and given that it clearly states, that this is an estimate I'd stay that's still alright :)

Comment: It's correct, is just an estimation. However, use the du `--apparent-size` option because it match better with the tar command result. I will update the answer with this option (and the referred link, take a look)

Comment: I'm actually using this for the extraction of a compressed archive, so I am using `xz --robot --list` to get the uncompressed size and feed that into your solution. But thanks for the update nonetheless!

Comment: This is a really great tar hack! I love it. A great suggestion is to modify to use `[--->]` style by: (a) using `49` in the CHECKPOINT, and (b) using `--checkpoint-action="ttyout=\b->"`. That is a backspace. And a space after the `[ `.

Answer (score 28):

**Using only tar**

`tar` has the option (since v1.12) to print status information on signals using `--totals=$SIGNO`, e.g.:

```
tar --totals=USR1 -czf output.tar input.file
Total bytes written: 6005319680 (5.6GiB, 23MiB/s)
```

The `Total bytes written: [...]` information gets printed on every USR1 signal, e.g.:

```
pkill -SIGUSR1 tar
```

Source:

- [gnu.org - GNU tar - 3.7 Checking tar progress](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/verbose.html)

Comment: And to know the total original size, we can use `du -hs /path`. But how can we estimate the total bytes to be written when using the `-z` flag? I assume it would be less than the original size

Comment: I have asked a Q related to my comment [on unix.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/551812/how-does-the-tar-flag-totals-interact-with-the-z-flag)

Answer (score 6):

Method based upon [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#usage):

```
tar -v -xf tarfile.tar -C TARGET_DIR | tqdm --total $(tar -tvf tarfile.tar | wc -l) > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 4):

You won't see how much is left, but you will see that it is progressing with a very simple addition to your command `--checkpoint=1000`

```
# tar  xf  file.tar --checkpoint=1000
tar: Read checkpoint 1000
tar: Read checkpoint 2000
tar: Read checkpoint 3000
tar: Read checkpoint 4000
tar: Read checkpoint 5000
tar: Read checkpoint 6000
...
```

More details on https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_25.html

Answer (score 3):

Just noticed the comment about MacOS, and while I think the solution from @akira (and pv) is *much* neater I thought I'd chase a hunch and a quick playaround in my MacOS box with tar and sending it a SIGINFO signal. Funnily enough, it worked :) if you're on a BSD-like system, this *should* work, but on a Linux box, you might need to send a SIGUSR1, and/or `tar` might not work the same way.

The down side is that it will only provide you with an output (on stdout) showing you how far through the current file it is since I'm guessing it has no idea about how big the data stream it's getting is.

So yes, an alternative approach would be to fire up tar and periodically send it SIGINFOs anytime you want to know how far it's gotten. How to do this?

### The ad-hoc, manual approach

If you want to be able to check status on an ad-hoc basis, you can hit `control-T` (as Brian Swift mentioned) in the relevant window which will send the SIGINFO signal across. One issue with that is it will send it to your entire chain I believe, so if you are doing:

```
% tar cvf - folder-with-big-files | bzip2 -c > big-files.tar.bz2
```

You will also see bzip2 report it's status along with tar:

```
a folder-with-big-files/big-file.imgload 0.79  cmd: bzip2 13325 running 
      14 0.27u 1.02s 

      adding folder-with-big-files/big-file.imgload (17760256 / 32311520)
```

This works nicely if you just want to check if that `tar` you're running is stuck, or just slow. You probably don't need to worry too much about formatting issues in this case, since it's only a quick check..

### The sort of automated approach

If you know it's going to take a while, but want something like a progress indicator, an alternative would be to fire off your tar process and in another terminal work out it's PID and then throw it into a script that just repeatedly sends a signal over. For example, if you have the following scriptlet (and invoke it as say `script.sh PID-to-signal interval-to-signal-at`):

```
#!/bin/sh

PID=$1
INTERVAL=$2
SIGNAL=29      # excuse the voodoo, bash gets the translation of SIGINFO, 
               # sh won't..

kill -0 $PID   # invoke a quick check to see if the PID is present AND that
               # you can access it..

echo "this process is $$, sending signal $SIGNAL to $PID every $INTERVAL s"
while [ $? -eq 0 ]; do
     sleep $INTERVAL;
     kill -$SIGNAL $PID;    # The kill signalling must be the last statement
                            # or else the $? conditional test won't work
done
echo "PID $PID no longer accessible, tar finished?"
```

If you invoke it this way, since you're targeting only `tar` you'll get an output more like this

```
a folder-with-big-files/tinyfile.1
a folder-with-big-files/tinyfile.2
a folder-with-big-files/tinyfile.3
a folder-with-big-files/bigfile.1
adding folder-with-big-files/bigfile.1 (124612 / 94377241)
adding folder-with-big-files/bigfile.1 (723612 / 94377241)
...
```

which I admit, is kinda pretty.

Last but not least - my scripting is kinda rusty, so if anyone wants to go in and clean up/fix/improve the code, go for your life :)

Comment: If running `tar` on the command line, typing `control-T` will send it a SIGINFO. If this was in a script it would be done with `kill -INFO pid`

Comment: Completely forgot about `control-T`, I clearly have gotten used to spamming too many console windows for my own good..

Comment: why can't I see -SIGINFO when doing `kill -l`

Comment: @FelipeAlvarez Because you have probably not been on a BSD/MAC OS. See also: [SIGINFO on GNU Linux (Arch Linux) missing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179481/siginfo-on-gnu-linux-arch-linux-missing)

Comment: @tanantish You could get rid of the "voodoo" (your wording not mine ;P ) by using `SIGNAL=$(kill -l SIGINFO)`, which would have the advantage of failing on systems without `SIGINFO`

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [Noah Spurrier’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3554912)

```sh
function tar {
  local bf so
  so=${*: -1}
  case $(file "$so" | awk '{print$2}') in
  XZ) bf=$(xz -lv "$so" |
    perl -MPOSIX -ane '$.==11 && print ceil $F[5]/50688') ;;
  gzip) bf=$(gzip -l "$so" |
    perl -MPOSIX -ane '$.==2 && print ceil $F[1]/50688') ;;
  directory) bf=$(find "$so" -type f | xargs du -B512 --apparent-size |
    perl -MPOSIX -ane '$bk += $F[0]+1; END {print ceil $bk/100}') ;;
  esac
  command tar "$@" --blocking-factor=$bf \
    --checkpoint-action='ttyout=%u%\r' --checkpoint=1
}
```

[Source](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/54f487f/.bashrc#L50-L63)

Comment: A little context and explanation maybe?

Answer (score 2):

On **macOS**, first make sure that you have all the commands available, and install the missing ones (e.g. `pv`) using [brew](https://brew.sh/).

If you only want to `tar` **without compression**, go with:

```
tar -c folder-with-big-files | pv -s $[$(du -sk folder-with-big-files | awk '{print $1}') * 1024] > folder-with-big-files.tar
```

If you want to **compress**, go with:

```
tar cf - folder-with-big-files -P | pv -s $[$(du -sk folder-with-big-files | awk '{print $1}') * 1024] | gzip > folder-with-big-files.tar.gz
```

> Note: It may take a while before the progress bar appears. Try on a smaller folder first to make sure it works, then move to folder-with-big-files.

Answer (score 2):

### For simple *extracting* with `pv`.

```bsh
pv mysql.tar.gz | tar -x
```

You'll get an output like this:

```bsh
 249MiB 0:00:19 [14.0MiB/s] [==>                               ] 10% ETA 0:02:44
```

Here it is in action:

[image]

To install `pv` on macOS just use Homebrew with:

```bsh
brew install pv
```

On other systems, you can look at the source repo [here](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml).

Answer (score 1):

**If you known the file number instead of total size of all of them:**

an alternative (less accurate but suitable) is to use the -l option and send in the unix pipe the filenames instead of data content.

Let's have 12345 files into *mydir*, command is:

```
[myhost@myuser mydir]$ tar cfvz ~/mytarfile.tgz .|pv -s 12345 -l > /dev/null
```

you can know such value in advance (because of your use case) or use some command like *find+wc* to discover it:

```
[myhost@myuser mydir]$ find | wc -l
12345
```

Comment: So, why not put this command into sub-command? =)

Comment: `tar cfvz ~/mytarfile.tgz . | pv -s $(find . | wc -l) -l > /dev/null`. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

[image: better looking progress bar]

Install the dialog and pv commands with

```
sudo apt-get install dialog pv
```

and then execute tar like this

```
(tar cf - /folder-with-big-files | pv -n -s $(du -sb /folder-with-big-files | awk '{print $1}') | gzip -9 > big-files.tar) 2>&1 | dialog --gauge 'Your backup is in progress...' 7 70
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with using 7z:

```
7z a example.tar example/
```

This will show the scanning drive stage

```
Scanning the drive:
2608M 139834 Scan  example/file.txt
```

as well as some other useful information to watch.

```
Scanning the drive:
157318 folders, 601997 files, 13683142277 bytes (13 GiB)           

Creating archive: example.tar

Items to compress: 759315

    3% 29587 + example/file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some numbers of a prometheus (metrics data) backup on Debian/buster AMD64:

```
root# cd /path/to/prometheus/
root# tar -cf - ./metrics | ( pv -p --timer --rate --bytes > prometheus-metrics.tar )
```

Canceled this job as there was not enough disk-space available.

Experimenting with `zstd` as compressor for `tar` with monitoring the progress using `pv`:

```
root# apt-get update
root# apt-get install zstd pv

root# tar -c --zstd -f - ./metrics | ( pv -p --timer --rate --bytes > prometheus-metrics.tar.zst )
10.2GiB 0:11:50 [14.7MiB/s]

root# du -s -h prometheus
62G    prometheus

root# du -s -h prometheus-metrics.tar.zst
11G    prometheus-metrics.tar.zst
```

Answer (score 0):

In my daily use I don't need to know the exact percent-level progress of the operation,  only if it is working and (sometimes) how much it is near completion.

I solve this need minimally by showing the number of files processed in its own line; in Bash:

```
let n=0; tar zcvf files.tgz directory | while read LINE; do printf "\r%d" $((n++)) ; done ; echo
```

As I use this a lot, I defined a function alias in .bashrc:

```
function pvl { declare -i n=0; while read L ; do printf "\r%d" $((++n)) ; done ; echo ; }
```

Then simply:

```
tar zcvf files.tgz directory | pvl
```

I can compute the number of files in advance if needed with `find directory | wc -l` (Or better using the same function shown [`find directory | pvl`] to squash my impatience!).

Another example, setting rights for a virtual website (after that, a `chown -R` is fast because the filenames are in the filesystem cache):

```
find /site -print -type d -exec chmod 2750 "{}" \; -o -type f -exec chmod 640 "{}" | pvl
```

It's true this lateral processing could slow the main operation, but I think printing a return character and a few digits cannot be too expensive (besides that, waiting for the next equal sign to appear or percent digit to change feels slow compared with the subjective blazing speed of changing digits!).