# Tar backup with progress bar

Tags: ubuntu, backup, tar, progress-bar

I would like to add a progress bar to my tar backup command. I found out that the [bar](http://www.theiling.de/projects/bar.html) shell script should be able to do this, but I am unable to figure out the correct command.

```
sudo tar pzcf - /media/data | bar > /media/backups/backup.tar.gz
```

With the above command I was able to display some information, but no progress bar yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to see any tar progress per file?](http://superuser.com/questions/168749/is-there-a-way-to-see-any-tar-progress-per-file)

Comment: Best answer by far is [this](https://superuser.com/a/1230259/116221). Not using any external dependencies, like `pv`. Very efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but this isn't possible. From the file `bar` itself:

```
Synopsis:
  'bar' works just like 'cat', but shows a progress bar in ASCII art on stderr.
  The script's main function is meant to be usable in any Bourne shell to be
  suitable for install scripts without the need for any additional tool.
```

The problem is that, in order to display the progress bar, `bar` has to know the file's size first.

For **extracting** an archieve, that's no problem: If `backup.tar` is `100 MiB` big and `50 MiB` have been processed so far, we're at `50 %`.

However, for **creating** an archieve, `bar` reads from `stdin`, which is infinite for all practical purposes. As the [documentation](http://www.theiling.de/projects/bar.html#bugs) says:

> Infinite streams are not nice: the bar is only displayed at 0% and at 100%. [...]

---

The only way to display progress bars for backup purposes I can think of (besides compiling a custom version of *tar with bar*) is:

1. Calculate the accumulated size of the files `/media/data`.
2. Create `backup.tar` and append the files from `/media/data` one by one.
3. After each file, calculate the current percentage and display it.
4. gzip `backup.tar` (you **can** use `tar` for this).

#### Example:

```
TOTAL=$(du -b /media/data | grep -oP "^\d+")
CURRENT=0
echo "Archiving:"
IFS="
"
for FILE in $(find /media/data -type f); do 
    tar rf backup.tar $FILE
    CURRENT=$(($CURRENT+$(du -b $FILE | grep -oP "^\d+")))
    echo -en "\r"$((100*($CURRENT-1)/$TOTAL+1))"%"
done
echo
echo "Compressing:"
bar backup.tar | gzip > backup.tar.gz
rm backup.tar
```

#### Caution:

- This will probably slow down your backup progress.
- File names may not contain newline characters.