# Tar with progress but without compression

Tags: ubuntu, bash, tar, progress

There are a lot of answers on how to create a `tar.gz` file with progress updates (ie. [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/665181/101893), copied below)

```
tar cf - /folder-with-big-files -P | pv -s $(du -sb /folder-with-big-files | awk '{print $1}') | gzip > big-files.tar.gz
```

But how do I see the progress if I am tarring files without compression like so

```
tar -cvf output.tar folder/to/tar
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While the accepted solution works it is just a bit of an abuse of process. There is a simpler and more elegant/correct solution -

```
tar -c /folder-with-big-files | pv -s $(du -sb /folder-with-big-files | awk '{print $1}') > bigfiles.tar
```

tar stands for Tape ARchive - and is designed to deal with streams.  the "f" in "cf" tells tar to specifically create a file - rather then do this and specify a "-" to use stdout as this file.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that, davidgo. Note that the two folder paths (currently showing as /folder and /folder-with-big-files) need to match, as in @Kevin Rockwell's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of putting the output through gzip, output to a file: 
`tar cf - /folder-with-big-files -P | pv -s $(du -sb /folder-with-big-files | awk '{print $1}') > big-files.tar`